Struggling to install on python
I recently started delving into python (been postponing due to the learning curve!) and am facing some struggles right off the bat. I want to start out working with spreadsheets alongside a tutorial, but cannot get the necessary tools to install and work.
I've installed Python 3.12, followed by the latest Visual Studio Code, where I am mainly operating in, and then tried to install openpyxl to work on excel spreadsheets. I've got some code typed in a python project, but require openpyxl to compile and execute the code. Upon trying to install openpyxl, I received an error "no such file or directory". It appeared through troubleshooting that I require "setuptools" to be installed first, so off I went.
Trying to install setup tools following the guide at https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html didn't help much, as I ran into trouble figuring out how to operate the pip installations.
So off I go trying to figure out what/where/how pip works, but ran into trouble trying the suggestions at this page https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_pip.asp. I've opened CMD and tried to execute the suggest install commands for setuptools, but I receive the error "the system cannot find the path specified. I don't know what is missing or what I'm doing wrong to get the errors below:
my attempted filepath in cmd
and I'm trying to point it to this directory, assuming it is correct:
my filepath in python scripts folder
At this point I'm quite frustrated by the whole process of each library/script requiring another library/script requiring another, and the root not working, causing everything else to not work.
I would please appreciate handholding/signposting in getting this resolved!

You should create a new virt environment for your project and install the packages you need using VS 'Python Environments". I think that setuptools will be included as part of the creation of the virt env. If you create a requirements.txt file which includes the line openpyxl==3.1.5 and Openpyxl will be installed as the environment is created.

this is my solution. You can refer to it, if you have any difficulty, please comment and I will help.
Firstly, I don't know exactly your os system, so base on you os, you can install pip in your laptop or pc.

Window: https://www.liquidweb.com/blog/install-pip-windows/
Ubuntu: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-24-04

For me, I use conda for managing my python environment, this's optional, so if you want to install it, you can access and install following the instructions.

Window: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/windows.html
Ubuntu: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html

For setuptools, I haven'y installed this library yet, but my code still run good, so I think you don't neet install setuptools to run openpyxl.
In Visual Code, in the extensions, you can install python directly. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkVLNvFh0-M)
For the first install python environment, I usually do the initial step like this (https://www.liquidweb.com/help-docs/adding-python-path-to-windows-10-or-11-path-environment-variable/), you can access and follow the instructions.
After the above things, you can check pip version:
pip --version and run pip install openpyxl
Hope the aboves helps you good.

Thank you for the guidance. It has helped with some items missing or not working as intended, including pip.
I installed a new windows partition and fresh python and vs code according to the video you shared.
I then ran therun pip install openpyxl which indeed installed openpyxl.
I then started a fresh main.py file in the root projects folder (which was accepted as trusted), and copied my "Test file.xlsx" to the folder.
When I run the code in the image I posted at link, I get the error as shown in the 2nd image. I'm stumped! Please help?

I saw your error. This solution is replacing the file name to the sheet name what you want to load data.
For example, the file name is 'name_file.xlsx', and the excel file contains 2 sheet, the name are 'sheet 1' and 'sheet 2'. When you load data from 'sheet 2', the code below:
wb = load_workbook('name_file.xlsx')
ws = wb['sheet 2']
I think the code will work. You can try. If the code get error, please give me your code, I will fix it.

I managed to execute after making this last suggested change.
Thank you very much for your help and walkthroughs!
